# Emacs create broken dot hash filename symlink when editing

Tags: emacs, backup, symlink

When I work with Emacs when I change something and don't save it create .#File which is broken symlink (which seem it's some kind of backup file)

When I open a file `xxxx` and type something, I've got this:

```
file .#xxxx 
.#xxxx: broken symbolic link to `kuba@jcubic.1581:1393008109'
```

Why this symlink is broken, what is the purpose of that files and how to make it work?

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.2.1

Comment: This is a lock to prevent other instances of Emacs from editing the same file.

Comment: I see, is it possilbe to make it link to existing file, because it give me error when I run `find | xargs grep`

Comment: @jcubic, either save the file, ignore the errors or use `rgrep` which is superior to `find | grep`.